# File sharing Ubuntu 13.04 & Windows 7

Tags: file-sharing

COMPLETE NOOB QUESTION.

Hey I have just recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP Pavillion DM1 laptop which is wireless. I have 2 Windows 7 machines connected via Ethernet and I am trying to set-up file sharing between them, but no matter what I do I can't get it working.

Windows just refuses to see it anywhere on either machine and I can get to a point where the Windows machines is available on the Ubuntu machine, but either 1 or 2 things happen when I select it. It opens & nothing is in it, or it comes up with the workgroup folder and when I open it, it has the Ubuntu folders in it.

I have full file sharing enabled on my Windows machines, I am seriously at a complete loss. I have seen that its harder to accomplish on the newer versions of Ubuntu but I'm not sure how accurate this is.

Comment: Have you set up samba shares on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: As for the windows machine, it sounds like it might be the firewall. Test this by turning it off and then trying to access from Ubuntu.